# Work on a remote project with Eclipse via SSH and SVN+SSH (2 remote Linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, c++, eclipse

I have the following boxes:

a) A Windows box with Eclipse CDT(or PTP)

b) A Linux box,including Compiler, accessible for me only via SSH.

c) A Linux box, including SVN Source, accessible for me only via SSH

Both the compiler and the hardware required to build and run my project is only on machine B.

I'd like to work "transparently" from a Windows box on that project using Eclipse CDT -or PTP - and be able to build, run and debug the project remotely from within the IDE.

How do I set up that:

The building will work? Any simpler solutions than writing a local makefile which would rsync the project and then call a remote makefile to initiate the actual build? Does Eclipse managed build have a feature for that?
The debugging will work?
Preferably - the Eclipse CDT -or PTP-code indexing will work? Do I have to copy all required header files from machine B to machine A and add them to include path manually?

Comment: I'm sure that Eclipse has something (probably a plugin) for version control with `svn` & `git`

Comment: BTW, it would be much simpler for you to install Linux on your own laptop, and you'll learn a big lot by using Linux daily.

Comment: Please go through [Target Management in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/)

Comment: @Basile   ,in fact, it has, but don't work like netbean  Remote System Explorer and of course, PTP,

Comment: @Basile   I familiar with Linux, desktop,server, Lfs and embedded , but the problem is we have to connect to remote server as well as remote svn from our work station at place of work

Comment: It is easily doable with `emacs`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch   for short time i.e. my case, emacs is not a solution, its just another problem....i can do this by putty and vi but i need to ability of IDE...